# R stargazer function produced table is not aligned

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I have three regression and all variables name are identical.

`reg1<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=data1)`

`reg2<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=data2)`

`reg3<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4,data=data3)`

Then I try to do:
`stargazer(reg1,reg2,reg3,type="text",keep.stat = "all",align = TRUE)`

The table is produced but misplaced (line 1, row 1-4 are the result for reg1, but line 2, row 5-8 are the result for reg 2, row 9-12 for reg3).

Can anyone suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you go more into detail, what you expect the output to look like? When you use identical models (variables) with different datasets, I don't see misplaced output.

```
library("plm")
library("stargazer")

data("Produc", package = "plm")

model1 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
              data = Produc, 
              index = c("state","year"),
              method="pooling")

model2 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
              data = Produc, 
              index = c("state","year"),
              method="between")

model3 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
              data = Produc, 
              index = c("state","year"),
              method="within")

stargazer(model1,model2,model3,type="text",keep.stat = "all",align = TRUE)
stargazer(model1,model2,model3,type="latex",keep.stat = "all",align = TRUE, out="output.tex")
```

[image]

Notice that the `align` option only works in latex output and only if you have loaded the package `dcolumn`. Latex, with and without the `dcolumn`:

[image]